# Formatting and capturing sys.exc_info error messages

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

I'm trying to format and get the information from sys.exc_info by  `''.join(traceback.format_stack())`, but with no luck, Any suggestions on how I can get all the information from sys.esc_info, into  a string. I need to finally write all this information into a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sys.exc_info()` to get the exception triplet. To get a string from the trace, use `traceback.format_tb()`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import traceback

try:
    raise RuntimeError("This is an error")
except:
    exception_type, exception_value, trace = sys.exc_info()
    print(f"Exception type: {exception_type}") # <class 'RuntimeError'>
    print(f"Exception value: {exception_value}") # This is an error

    trace_string = "".join(traceback.format_tb(trace))
    print(f"Stack trace:\n{trace_string}")
    # File "/home/pierre/stackoverflow.py", line 5, in <module>
    #     raise RuntimeError("This is an error")
```